# What do we say "A big Flower Pot" in English

Tags: translation

I have a Big Pot in which there is a Big Plant. But I don't know what do we say it in english in my native language, we say it, "Gamla"
Also, there is no Flower it! :P
It looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4z35d4kn2f6b57/Nature-Pot-and-Plant-Photograph-520x693.jpg

Comment: It's a plant, so 'plant pot'. Telling us what your native language is would also be helpful.

Comment: It's entirely proper to call it just *a big pot*. If you're talking about planting something in it, nobody will think you're talking about a cooking pot.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a [planter](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/planter):

> 3) A container, usually decorative, for potted or unpotted house plants

Answer (score 0):

You may call it as a [plant pot](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plant-pot) or even [flowerpot](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flowerpot).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flowerpot_1.jpg) shows a picture of 'flowerpot' which is empty and not necessarily to have flowers in it.

[image]

As for the dictionary,

> [flowerpot (n)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flowerpot) - (Horticulture) a pot in which **plants** are grown.

Plants **may or may not** have flowers there.

**Important-** Not to confuse it with pot plant which means...

> [pot plant (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/POTPLANT) - *A plant suitable for growing in a flowerpot (especially indoors).*

Comment: Actually a pot plant is something else entirely ;-)

Comment: @Jim I defined it but put this additionally as it contains the same words in reverse order. For non-native speakers, I'm pretty sure it'll be helpful :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if people start going around talking about "pot plants" according to your definition **They will be misunderstood**

Comment: @Jim oops, that's not **my** definition! If you don't like WW there, here's another one - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pot%20plant

Comment: Sorry Maulik, my point is that a "pot plant" almost exclusively refers to a marijuana plant. I don't know any native language speaker who would refer to any plant in a pot or any plant capable of being potted (i.e., houseplants or indoor plants) as a pot plant.

Comment: Many older British gardeners would still use "pot plant" with no reference to drugs, but the "correct" British English term is now "potted plants". (See Google for examples of use). Also, large plant pots for outdoor use are sometimes just called "containers", in BrEng, especially if they are made in a different shape or material from small flowerpots.